# MVC MusicStore App Question

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to dive into MVC3 and very excited to learn it. I am trying to build this:
http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/
from scratch. After downloading SampleData.cs into my Models folder and making these changes into my Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData());
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

I am getting very weird kind of output. Even though I commented out total data in SampleData.cs, the Genre is still showing up in my locahost/Store/Index. And here is more interesting part, in my desktop pc it is showing up, but when I copy my solution into USB Drive and run it in my laptop it shows 0 Genre.

Dont know what is going on here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SampleData` class inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. If the model doesn't change, the database is left as it is.

So, did you run the application on the desktop before commenting out the data generation code in `Seed`? If so, that's how the data got there (the original version of `Seed` was used during the initial db creation).

You could **drop the database manually**, or you could **add a temporary property to the model**. In either case, the initializer will automatically recreate the db for you on the next run using your new (no-data) version of `SampleData.Seed`.

**EDIT** There is actually another option which is to change `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`; however, this really will do it each time the app starts, so don't leave it that way if you want your data to persist.